Rename and sort pictures and videos from Google Takeout
I'm trying to automatically rename and sort pictures and videos from a Google Photos export (Google Takeout) using a bash script. Structure of the Google Photos directory after download:
.
├── Google Photos
│   ├── Accident Mercedes
│   │   ├── IMG_9660.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_9660.JPG.json
│   │   └── metadata.json
│   ├── Ardennen vrienden Ine
│   │   ├── 0906b711-2fc6-4b29-8daf-1203aad2f2ca.jpg
│   │   ├── 0906b711-2fc6-4b29-8daf-1203aad2f2ca.jpg.json
│   │   ├── 41ADBC31-C2FB-4489-A316-81464EA04F18.mp4
│   │   ├── 41ADBC31-C2FB-4489-A316-81464EA04F18.mp4.json
│   │   ├── IMG_0414.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_0414.JPG.json
│   │   └── metadata.json
│   ├── Audi Q3 Ine
│   │   ├── IMG_5602.JPG
│   │   ├── IMG_5602.JPG.json
│   │   ├── IMG_5614.MOV
│   │   ├── IMG_5614.MOV.json
│   │   └── metadata.json
...

End result I would like to achieve, where the filename is formatted like %d%m%Y_%H%M%S%2N.lower_case_extension and the directories are grouped per year and split over two main video and photo directories:
.
├── Photo
│   ├── 2022
│   │   ├── Accident Mercedes
│   │   │   ├── 17052022_15563312.jpg
│   │   │   ├── 17052022_15563817.jpg
│   │   │   ├── 17052022_15564918.jpg
│   │   ├── Ardennen vrienden Ine
│   │   │   ├── 20072022_21241609.jpg
│   │   │   ├── 20072022_21292212.jpg
│   │   │   ├── 20072022_21310924.jpg
├── Video
│   ├── 2022
│   │   ├── Accident Mercedes
│   │   │   ├── 17052022_15563316.mp4
│   │   │   ├── 17052022_15563818.mov
│   │   ├── Ardennen vrienden Ine
│   │   │   ├── 20072022_21241645.mp4
...

I've tried creating a bash script for the renaming part, however it's not working, since it seems to use last edit date and not creation date, despite -r option. Unable to figure out how to lowercase the extension.
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1"

for d in *; do
  cd "$d"
  for f in *.jpg *.JPG *.MOV *.mov *.mp4 *.MP4 *.heic; do
    echo "./$d/$f"
    new_name=$(date -r "$f" +"%d%m%Y_%H%M%S%2N")
    ext="${f##*.}"
    mv "$f" "${new_name}.${ext}"
  done

  rm -rf "*.desktop.ini"
  rm -rf "*.json"
done

Remarks:

I need to use milliseconds to avoid files being removed if taken at exact same second.
I would like to remove all *.json and *.ini files.

I've tried creating another bash script for the sorting part, however it's only moving files and not directories containing those files.
#!/bin/bash

cd "$1"
mkdir Video
cd Video
mkdir -p {2000..2024}

c=2000
while [ $c -lt 2024 ]; do
   find "$2" -iname "*$c_*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ./$c
   let c=c+1
done

cd "$1"
mkdir Photos
cd Photos
mkdir -p {2000..2024}

c=2000
while [ $c -lt 2024 ]; do
   find "$2" -iname "*$c_*.mp4" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} ./$c
   let c=c+1
done

Thanks in advance for help!

For lowercase, use simply bash syntax like: ${ext,,}

To obtain creation file date, you could use stat command like this: date -d @$(stat --format="%W" "$f") +"%d%m%Y_%H%M%S%2N"

I'm not a fan about cd command in scripts. Do you try to use tree command? Like this: tree -if "$1"

Please read the [tag:bash] tag you have included, and copy/paste your code to https://shellcheck.net , correct any issues flagged and update your question (there are numerous issues in your code). Good luck.

near the top of your script (before any assignments to ext) you can run unset ext; declare -l ext (only needs to be done once in the script) to force all follow-on assignments to ext to be automatically converted to lowercase

in the first bash script you run cd "$d" but never cd back 'up' to where you started, so on the next pass through the loop cd "$d" will fail because you're still sitting in the $d from the previous pass through the loop; also consider that for d in * will pick up everything in the current directory ... directories, files and the literal * if there are no dirs/files, so consider a) validating that $d is a directory or b) populate the loop with the results of a find . -maxdepth 1 -type d

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

A subshell can be used for the cd, you could try something like this.
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob
GooglePhotos=(Google\ Photos/*/)
shopt -u nullglob

for d in "${GooglePhotos[@]}" ; do
  cwd=
  ext=
  file_type=
  mod_year=
  old_file_name=
  new_file_name=
  declare -a files
  (
    cd "$d" || exit
    shopt -s nullglob
    files=(*)
    shopt -u nullglob

    for f in "${!files[@]}"; do
      if [[ "${files[$f]}" == *.@(ini|json) ]]; then
        # rm -rf -- "${files[$f]}"
        break
      else
        ext=${files[$f]##*.}
        ext=${ext,,}
        old_file_name="${files[$f]}"
        cwd="$(basename -- "$PWD")"
        mod_year="$(date -r "${files[$f]}" '+%Y')"
        file_type="$(file --mime-type -b -- "${files[$f]}")"
        new_file_name="$(date -r "${files[$f]}" '+%d%m%Y_%H%M%S%2N').${ext}"

        if [[ "$file_type" == video/* ]]; then
          mkdir -pv "../Google/Video/$mod_year/$cwd" || exit
          cp -v -- "$old_file_name" "../Google/Video/$mod_year/$cwd/$new_file_name" || exit
        elif [[ "$file_type" == image/* ]]; then
          mkdir -pv "../Google/Photo/$mod_year/$cwd/" || exit
          cp -v -- "$old_file_name" "../Google/Photo/$mod_year/$cwd/$new_file_name" || exit
        fi
      fi
      unset -v 'files[f]'
    done
    files=("${files[@]}")
  )
done



A directory named Google/ is created below/one level of your Google Photo directory.
Nothing is deleted or moved, files ending in .ini and .json. are ignored,
Copies the files with the new directory/file names accordingly.
Uncomment the rm and change cp to mv if satisfied with the output/outcome/result.
Change the destination directory to your own hearts content.
Use stat as mentioned in the comments for the creation date, although it might not be available on some os/file system.
See How Can I check If a directory is empty (Consider dotglob also)
Why check the error of the cd command (The cd in a subshell included)
See Check/compare variable value multiple times for the *.@(ini|json) glob/pattern.


Impressive, it works! Indeed, looks like stat function isn't working when using Windows Subsystem for Linux to capture the creation date of a file that is in a Windows directory.
